# Accessing BBM chat

Tags: blackberry, bb-messenger

I want to develop an application that will use the BBM chat history .As I have read the BBM stores its chat in a .csv file format.I want to make an application that once installed on phone will access the .CSV file data and store it some where else.

If this is not possible then does Blackberry provide BBM API to access the chat history of user.

I don't know that it is possible or not but Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this help? http://notely.blogspot.co.uk/2010/02/bbm-messenger-log-cleanup-script.html

Comment: Also I think this is not correct:  " BBM stores its chat in a .csv file format".  What I think is correct is that if you ask BBM to save its chat, it will save it in this format.  It does not save chat logs unless the user requests it.